# &leq; and &geq; symbols on internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, character

I have noticed that the symbols ≥ and ≤ are broken on Internet Explorer: they display as `&geq;` and `&leq;` instead of as the actual symbol (at least on IE9 under Win7).

Is there any way to display the actual characters ≤ and ≥ on Internet Explorer (e.g. another way to write it, a javascript fix...)? I'd need to show them on a few places on my site, and I'd like the site to be viewable for Internet Explorer too.

Comment: Why don't you just use them directly?

Comment: Btw it's been implemented in IE10.

Comment: What do you mean by directly? Even if I visit even this page in IE, it doesn't display correctly.

Comment: I mean the characters. Can't you use ≥ directly? Just because a character is not on the keyboard does not mean that you can't have it in your HTML source code.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Strange, I thought they were always converted to &..; notation internally. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the characters “≥” and “≤” directly, provided that you page is UTF-8 encoded and declared as such. If this is not possible or convenient enough, you can use the character references `&#x2265;` and `&#x2264;` (or their decimal equivalents).

Alternatively, you can use the older entity references `&ge;` and `&le;`, which have the same meaning as `&geq;` and `&leq;` but are much better supported (universally).

Entity references such as `&geq;` (as opposite to the set of [entities as defined in HTML 4.01](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/guide/entities.html)) should be avoided. They add nothing to the expressive power of the HTML language; they just provide a deceptive quasi-mnemonic alternative to character references. They were introduced in HTML5 drafts mainly because they are defined in MathML, and less than two years ago *no* browser supported them, so there is still a large number of browsers that treat them as undefined, displaying them literally.

Comment: Aha, so `&ge;` and `&le;` are the correct syntax according to that table. And indeed, those work, thanks!

Comment: @user1111929, thanks, I did not remember that those entities are defined in HTML 4. I’ll update my answer.